# Rails cookies value different from controler with helper scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ENV:

Rails 3.2.15
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

I set cookies in controller and read it from helper method, and two result is not same. Why?

```
# in controller
cookies[:"position"] = { :value => [ 100,200 ], :expires => 1.years.from_now }
# read it same time, it display value is an array [100, 200]
# But I read this cookies in another request, it display "100&200"


# in helper
module WelcomeHelper
  def get_position
    cookies[:"position"]
  end

end
```

```

`get_position` method return `100&200`

Where can I find some documation? I found in code, it discribled array can be stored in cookies directly and read it directly: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.15/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L45 , but why I stored an arry in cookies and result from read is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use non-string values for your cookies please convert them to JSON first.

```
# using the preferred 1.9 hash syntax and no need to quote "position"
cookies[:position] = { value: JSON.generate([ 100,200 ]), expires: 1.years.from_now }
```

Check the [Rails 4.1 documentation on Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Rails 3.2 documentation caused a slight confusion [on that issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12860) by implying that a Ruby array can be [stored directly](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.15/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L25) as a cookie value which was fixed recently [by using JSON dump/load](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/eebb813cec396a1c77f4b1fbe2baf2c2a023a11a) and subsequently [by the safer JSON generate/parse](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a373ec727f94fedfd9a64bff6c040b42880c46b9).

Comment: But why https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.15/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L25 ??

Comment: OK, I see the source of confusion. This was a reported bug and has been fixed since. Updated my answer to reflect that